# Friday zohar prayer at home

Tags: salat, sunni

I am an Indian now staying in gulf country outside from city in village area, there is a masjid (mosque) but so far we can’t go by walk there and not available the taxi in time, so for Friday prayer can we pray at room of Zohar?

Comment: if you leave early for the prayers then u will get the friday prayers. As you are staying in gulf nobody will stop you for going early for the prayers.

Comment: @Rehan, nice question. There are some special characteristics for offering Friday prayer which apparently you cannot do it at home. (otherwise it would good if we could...) Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a Friday prayer is not prayed with congregation with a khutba, then it should be offered as regular Zohr prayer.

Comment: please provide some references...

Answer (score 3):

Whoever did not attend the Friday prayer with the Muslims due to some lawful reason, such as illness or the like, or some other reasons, should pray the Zuhr prayer. Likewise, a woman prays the Zuhr prayer and so does the traveller and those living in the desert, as is proved by the Sunnah, and it is the opinion of the majority of the scholars, and no consideration should be paid to those who deviate from them.

Shaykh `Abdul-`Azeez Bin Baz